# Android studio - Proguard seems to ignore rules, resulting in build error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-proguard

I keep getting the following errors while trying to make a signed apk using proguard:

```
Warning:com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI: can't find referenced class org.json.simple.JSONArray
Warning:com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI$DropboxFileInfo: can't find referenced class org.json.simple.JSONValue
Warning:com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI$Entry: can't find referenced class org.json.simple.JSONArray
Warning:com.dropbox.client2.RESTUtility: can't find referenced class org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser
Warning:com.dropbox.client2.RESTUtility: can't find referenced class org.json.simple.parser.ParseException
Warning:com.dropbox.client2.jsonextract.JsonExtractionException: can't find referenced class org.json.simple.JSONValue
Warning:com.inmobi.ads.aj: can't find referenced class com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
Warning:com.inmobi.ads.aj: can't find referenced class com.squareup.picasso.Picasso$Builder
Warning:com.inmobi.ads.aj: can't find referenced class com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator
Warning:com.inmobi.ads.aj: can't find referenced class com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
Warning:com.inmobi.ads.aj: can't find referenced class com.squareup.picasso.Picasso$Builder
Warning:com.inmobi.ads.aj: can't find referenced class com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator
Warning:com.inmobi.ads.aj: can't find referenced class com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
```

Even though i have `-keep public class com.dropbox.** { *; }`  in my proguard rules studio keeps hitting a wall about dropbox.Same thing happens with inmobi classes. Any suggestions?

This is my proguard-rules file.

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

-keep public class com.dropbox.** { *; } 


# Appodeal
-keep class com.appodeal.** { *; }
-keep class org.nexage.** { *; }
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod, InnerClasses, Signature, JavascriptInterface

# Amazon
-keep class com.amazon.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.amazon.**

# Mopub
-keep public class com.mopub.**
-keepclassmembers class com.mopub.** { public *; }
-keep class * extends com.mopub.mobileads.CustomEventBanner {}
-keep class * extends com.mopub.mobileads.CustomEventInterstitial {}
-keep class * extends com.mopub.nativeads.CustomEventNative {}
-keep class * extends com.mopub.mobileads.CustomEventRewardedVideo {}
-dontwarn com.mopub.volley.toolbox.**

# Applovin
-keep class com.applovin.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.applovin.**

# Facebook
-keep class com.facebook.ads.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.avocarrot.**
-keep class com.avocarrot.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.avocarrot.** { *; }
-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
  public <init> (android.content.Context);
  public <init> (android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
  public <init> (android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
  public void set*(...);
}

-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
}


# Appodeal
-keep class com.appodeal.** { *; }
-keep class org.nexage.** { *; }
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod, InnerClasses, Signature, JavascriptInterface

# Amazon
-keep class com.amazon.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.amazon.**

# Mopub
-keep public class com.mopub.**
-keepclassmembers class com.mopub.** { public *; }
-keep class * extends com.mopub.mobileads.CustomEventBanner {}
-keep class * extends com.mopub.mobileads.CustomEventInterstitial {}
-keep class * extends com.mopub.nativeads.CustomEventNative {}
-keep class * extends com.mopub.mobileads.CustomEventRewardedVideo {}
-dontwarn com.mopub.volley.toolbox.**

# Applovin
-keep class com.applovin.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.applovin.**

# Facebook
-keep class com.facebook.ads.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.facebook.ads.**

# Chartboost
-keep class com.chartboost.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.chartboost.**

# Unity Ads
-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep class com.unity3d.** { *; }

# Yandex
-keep class com.yandex.metrica.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.yandex.metrica.**
-keep class com.yandex.mobile.ads.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.yandex.mobile.ads.**
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# StartApp
-keep class com.startapp.** { *;}
-dontwarn com.startapp.**
-keepattributes Exceptions, InnerClasses, Signature, Deprecated, SourceFile, LineNumberTable, *Annotation*, EnclosingMethod

# Flurry
-keep class com.flurry.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.flurry.**
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,Signature
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

# Avocarrot
-keep class com.avocarrot.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.avocarrot.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.avocarrot.**
-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
  public <init>(android.content.Context);
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
  public void set*(...);
}

# Adcolony
-keep class com.jirbo.adcolony.** { *;}
-keep class com.immersion.** { *;}
-dontnote com.immersion.**
-dontwarn android.webkit.**
-dontwarn com.jirbo.adcolony.**

# Vungle
-keep class com.vungle.** { public *; }
-keep class javax.inject.*
-keepattributes *Annotation*, Signature
-keep class dagger.*
-dontwarn com.vungle.**

# MyTarget
-keep class com.my.target.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.my.target.**
-keep class ru.mail.android.mytarget.** { *; }
-dontwarn ru.mail.android.mytarget.**

#Cheetah Mobile
-keep class com.cmcm.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.cmcm.**

# Tapjoy
-keep class com.tapjoy.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.tapjoy.**

# Revmob
-keep class com.revmob.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.revmob.**

# Admob
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.** { *; }

# Google
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil {*;}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

# Legacy
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.net.http.**

# Google Play Services library
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
  public static final *** NULL;
}
-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final *** CREATOR;
}
-keep @interface android.support.annotation.Keep
-keep @android.support.annotation.Keep class *
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
  @android.support.annotation.Keep <fields>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
  @android.support.annotation.Keep <methods>;
}
-keep @interface com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName
-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
  @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}
-keep @interface com.google.android.gms.common.util.DynamiteApi
-keep public @com.google.android.gms.common.util.DynamiteApi class * {
  public <fields>;
  public <methods>;
}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException {*;}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException {*;} 

# Google Play Services library 9.0.0 only
-dontwarn android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy
-keep public @com.google.android.gms.common.util.DynamiteApi class * { *; }

# support-v4
-keep class android.support.v4.app.Fragment { *; }
-keep class android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity { *; }
-keep class android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager { *; }
-keep class android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction { *; }
-keep class android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager { *; }
-keep class android.support.v4.util.LruCache { *; }
-keep class android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter { *; }
-keep class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager { *; }
-keep class android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat { *; }

# support-v7-recyclerview
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager { *; }


-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn com.google.appengine.**
-dontwarn javax.servlet.**

# Support classes for compatibility with older API versions

-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontnote android.support.**



-keep class org.** { *; }
-keep class com.inmobi.ads.** { *; }


-keep public class com.google.ads.** { public protected *; } 
-keep public class com.inmobi.androidsdk.** { public protected *; }
-keep public class com.millenialmedia.android.** { public protected *; }
-keep public class com.mobclix.android.sdk.** { public protected *; }
-keep public class com.jumptap.adtag.** { public protected *; }
```

Comment: would the downvoters care to say why they downvoted ?

Answer (score -1):

add below to ignore warnings

```
-dontwarn com.dropbox.**
-dontwarn com.inmobi.**
```

Comment: if i do that the i just dont get the error warning...it doesn't make the error go away.